# Explanation of PHP sessions with roles please

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, roles

I have a MySQL database. In that database I have table called `users`. In users I have `username`, `password`, `role`. If the role is `0` then it's a *user*. If the role is `1` then it's *admin*.

This is how the session set right now.

```
if($count==1){
        echo "true";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;  
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong";
    }
```

This is what I have at the top of the pages:

```
 session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location:login.php");
  }
```

I am confused about how to check again the role though. For example, if it's role 1 = they get admin pages if role 0 - user.

Currently, I have only 1 admin, and this is how I've been given them authorisation.

But I am not sure if this is correct. I need explanations please.

```
if ( 'admin' == $_SESSION['username'] ) {

    include('admin.php');
}
else {
    include('user.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

these two  function will check if a session is present and check the users permission.

```
function confirmed_login(){

    if(!isset($_SESSION['permission'])){    
        header('Location: login_redirect.php'); 
    }
}

function permission_admin($permission){

    if($permission != '1'){
        header('Location: login_redirect.php'); 
    }
}


function check_login($p) {

    permission_admin($p);
    confirmed_login();

}
```

simply call this function at the top of any restricted page like so:

```
check_login($SESSION['role']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should setup the role in the session and check not the username but it's role:

```
...
echo "true";
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
$_SESSION['password'] = $pass; 
$_SESSION['role'] = $role; 
...

if ($_SESSION['role'] == 1) {    
    include('admin.php');
} else {
    include('user.php');
}
```

or as an alternative set an admin variable and always check if that exists when user logs in:

```
...
echo "true";
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
$_SESSION['password'] = $pass; 
if($role == 1) {
   $_SESSION['admin'] = true; 
}
...

if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {    
    include('admin.php');
} else {
    include('user.php');
}
```

Comment: You set $_SESSION values only in the login.php (or during login), and you  actually should not set $_SESSION['password'] at all, thats a security flaw.

Comment: And you put session_start(); at the top of every php file (nevertheless login or not login), that way you can check if $_SESSION['admin'] is already set or not, any time.

Answer (score 0):

You have database connection in login.php, right? Why don't you use the connection and get the role information of the user if username and password exists in the database of course, then according to that role value you redirect the user like (I made connection with a procedure and calling that procedure and loading informations) And within the if you have to make the control whether the user exists or not ; rowcount>1 for example :

```
$role = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$conn = oci_connect(---);
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "begin packageX.login(:username,:password,:role); end;");

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":username", $username);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":password", $password);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":role", $role);
if ( $role == 1 and $username!="" and $password!="") {

    header( "Location: admin.php" );
}
else if($role == 0 and $username!="" and $password!=""){ 
    header( "Location: user.php" );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have database connection. I get confused about where to put what. I have three pages, and each page have two extra php pages (one for each user) so if it's user it would include this page and if it's admin it would include this page....

Comment: Okay, with your connection store the user's username, password and role information in variables. And then for example if the user exists in the table and then look at his role number, after that if the role is one you can use header( "Location: admin.php" ); otherwise you redirect the user header( "Location: user.php" );